# How to redirect to main component after success login

Tags: angular2-routing, angular4-router

I am a new in Angular2 and stacked on next step. My web site starts with a login page. I enter user and password( Login Component), receive from backend success response and want to redirect to the main page ( Main Component).
My project structure is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AanCV.png)

*login.component.ts*

```
 import { Component, OnInit, style } from '@angular/core';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
 import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
 import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
 import $ from 'jquery';
 import { parse } from 'url';
 import { FormControl, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
 import { LoginServiceService } from './login.service';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
 import { users } from './login.users';
 import {Router} from '@angular/router';




@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],  
})


export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
public data;

constructor(public jsonLoginDataService: LoginServiceService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
}
login(userName, password) { 
let user = new users(userName, password);
this.jsonLoginDataService.checkLogin(user).subscribe(
  function (success) {
    this.data = success;
    //this.datahandle(success);
    if(this.data.length==0)
    {
         console.log("User wasn't found");
    }
    else 
    {
      //Redirect to Main Component

    }
  },
  error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + 
  JSON.stringify(error)));

  }
  datahandle(jsonData) {
   let keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
   }
  }
```

*login.module.ts*

```
      import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
      import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
      import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
      import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
      import { TagCloudModule } from 'angular-tag-cloud-module';
      import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
      import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
      import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
      import { LoginServiceService } from './login.service';
      import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
      import { MainComponent } from '../main/main.component';
      import { routing } from './login.routing';

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            LoginComponent,    
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            TagCloudModule,
            NgbModule,
            MatDialogModule 

          ],
          providers: [LoginServiceService],
          bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
        })
        export class LoginModule { }
```

*main.component.ts*

```
        import { Component, OnInit, style } from '@angular/core';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
        import { CcDataServiceService } from './api.service';
        import { new_Item } from './main.newItem';
        import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
        import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table';
        import $ from 'jquery';
        import { new_Income } from './main.newIncome';
        import { parse } from 'url';


        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
        })




        @Injectable()
        export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
          public exp_total_amount: number;
          add_category: string;
          add_ex_budget: string;
          add_income_category: string;
          add_income_amount: number;
          public real_total_amount: number;
          public pass_new_month_amount: number;
          public total_income: number;
          public current_budget: number;
          real_amount: number;
          temp_amount: number;
          service: string;
          service1: string;
          expected_amount: number;
          deviation: number;
          left_amount: number;
          history: string;
          income_amount: number;
          purchase_date: string;
          public data;
          public data_Income;
          public real_data;
          public saving_progress: number;
          public balance_progress: number;
          public left_spend_amount: number;

          constructor(public jsonDataService: CcDataServiceService) {
          }
          ngOnInit() {
            this.loadData();
          }

          datahandle(jsonData) {
            //console.log('check your data' + JSON.stringify(jsonData)); //<-----check data
            // may parse your data 

            let keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
          }
          updateDeviation() {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
              this.data[i].deviation = Math.round((this.data[i].real_amount * 100) / (this.data[i].expected_amount) * 10) / 10;
            }
          }
          updateTotals() {
            this.exp_total_amount = 0;
            this.real_total_amount = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
              this.exp_total_amount += Math.round((this.data[i].expected_amount) * 10) / 10;
              this.real_total_amount += Math.round((this.data[i].real_amount) * 10) / 10;
              this.data[i].left_amount = Math.round((this.data[i].expected_amount - this.data[i].real_amount) * 10) / 10;
            }
            this.pass_new_month_amount = Math.round((this.exp_total_amount - this.real_total_amount) * 10) / 10;
            //this.  
            this.checkAmount();

          }
          updateCurrentBadget() {
            this.current_budget = Math.round(this.total_income - this.real_total_amount) * 10 / 10;
            this.saving_progress = Math.round(this.current_budget * 100 / this.total_income) * 10 / 10;
            this.balance_progress = Math.round(this.pass_new_month_amount * 100 / this.exp_total_amount) * 10 / 10;
            this.checkAmount();
          }
          updateIncome() {
            this.total_income = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.data_Income.length; i++) {
              this.total_income += Math.round((this.data_Income[i].income_amount) * 10) / 10;
            }
            this.checkAmount();
          }

          reloadPageData() {
            this.loadData();
            this.updateIncome();
            this.checkAmount();
            this.ngOnInit();
          }

          addCategory(add_category, add_ex_budget) {
            let new_item = new new_Item(add_category, add_ex_budget);
            this.jsonDataService.setCategory(new_item).subscribe(
              function (success) {
                this.data = success;
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
            this.updateTotals();
            this.reloadPageData();
            this.updateCurrentBadget();
            this.checkAmount();
          }
          addIncomeCategory(add_income_category, add_income_amount) {
            let new_income = new new_Income(add_income_category, add_income_amount);
            this.jsonDataService.setIncomeData(new_income).subscribe(
              function (success) {
                this.data = success;
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));

            this.updateIncome();
            this.reloadPageData();
            this.clearFields();
            this.checkAmount();
          }

          deleteCategory(service1) {
            this.jsonDataService.deleteCategory(service1).subscribe(
              function (success) {
                this.data = success;
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
            this.updateTotals();
            this.reloadPageData();
          }

          updateBudget(this) {
            let updatedData;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
              if (this.data[i].service === this.service) {
                this.data[i].real_amount = +this.data[i].real_amount;
                this.data[i].real_amount += this.temp_amount;
                this.data[i].history += "  $" + this.temp_amount + " - " + this.purchase_date + ";";
                updatedData = this.data[i];
              }
            }
            this.jsonDataService.performPayment(updatedData).subscribe(
              function (success) {
                this.data = success;
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));
            this.updateDeviation();
            this.updateTotals();
            this.updateCurrentBadget();
            this.clearFields();
            this.loadData();

          }

          hideLog() {
            if ($('#input_log').val() === "Show log") {
              $('#log_table').css('display', 'block');
              $('#input_log').val('Hide log');
            }
            else if ($('#input_log').val() === "Hide log") {
              $('#log_table').css('display', 'none');
              $('#input_log').val('Show log');
            }
          }

          clearFields() {
            $('input').each(function () {
              if (($(this).attr('type') == 'number') || ($(this).attr('type') == 'text'))
                $(this).val('');
            });
          }

          checkAmount() {
            let xx = (this);
            $('#budget_table tbody tr').each(function () {
              let y = parseInt($(this).children('td:eq(3)').text());
              if (y < 0) {
                $(this).children('td:eq(3)').css('color', "red ");
              }
              if (y > 0) {
                $(this).children('td:eq(3)').css('color', "green ");
              }
            });

            $('label').each(function () {
              let x = parseInt((this).innerHTML);
              if (xx.real_total_amount > xx.exp_total_amount) {
                if (x == xx.real_total_amount) {
                  $(this).css('color', "red ");
                }
              }
              if (xx.real_total_amount < xx.exp_total_amount) {
                if (x == xx.real_total_amount) {
                  $(this).css('color', "green ");
                }
              }

              if ((x == xx.pass_new_month_amount) && (xx.pass_new_month_amount < 0)) {
                $(this).css('color', "red ");
              }
              if ((x == xx.pass_new_month_amount) && (xx.pass_new_month_amount > 0)) {
                $(this).css('color', "green ");
              }

            });
            // Progress bar coloured
            $('.progress-bar').each(function () {
              let width_size = $(this).prop('style')['width'];
              let new_width = width_size.replace('%', '');
              if (new_width > 100) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
              }

            });
          }

          loadData() {
            let thisx = this;
            let thisi = this;
            this.jsonDataService.view_services(thisx).subscribe(
              function (success) {
                thisx.data = success;
                thisx.datahandle(success);
                thisx.updateDeviation();
                thisx.updateTotals();
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));

            this.jsonDataService.view_income(thisi).subscribe(
              function (success) {
                thisi.data_Income = success;
                thisi.updateIncome();
                thisi.updateCurrentBadget();
              },
              error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + JSON.stringify(error)));

          }


        }
```

*main.module.ts*

```
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
        import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
        import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
        import { TagCloudModule } from 'angular-tag-cloud-module';
        import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
        import { CcDataServiceService } from './api.service';
        import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
        import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
        // Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http
        //import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            MainComponent
          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            TagCloudModule,
            NgbModule,
            MatDialogModule,

          ],
          providers: [CcDataServiceService],
          bootstrap: [MainComponent]
        })
        export class MainModule { }
```

What I have to do for redirect to MainComponent?
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Create the Following for Manage Navigation and Routing

app.routing.ts

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core'
import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router'
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component.ts'
import {MainPageComponent} from './main/main.component'
export const routes:Routes=[
    {
        path:'',
        redirectTo:'login',
        pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        path:'login',
        component:LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path:'main',
        component:MainPageComponent
    }    
]
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

app.module.ts

```
import { routing } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [   
    routing
  ]
})
```

login.component.ts

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router'

constructor(public router:Router) { }

navigate(){
  this.router.navigate(['\main']);     //Add this line to navigate in your method
}
```

Add this line to where you want to place your navigation

app.component.html

```
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I hope this help and easy to understand..

learn routing visit this site
https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing

Comment: Glad to help you. It is useful answer please mark as answer.